# Django Model save methode

Tags: django, django-models

I trying to add a save method for an model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.Position:
        ProductImages.objects.filter(Position=self.Position, ProductID=self.ProductID).update(
            Position=self.Position+1)
```

It is working fine, but if I have an Image in Position 1 and one in 2 and add another in Position 1 then I have 2 times Images in Position 2. Is there an uncomplicated way to check all Positions with the ProductID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to update instances according to their own `Position` value:

```py
from django.db.models import F

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.Position:
        queryset = self.__class__._default_manager.filter(Position=self.Position, ProductID=self.ProductID)
        if self.pk:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        if queryset.exists():
            self.__class__._default_manager.filter(Position__gte=self.Position, ProductID=self.ProductID).update(Position=F('Position') + 1)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

> **Note**: Ideally Field names should be in `snake_case` not `PascalCase`. So it should be `position` not <s>`Position`</s>.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but it has the same effect, if I save another picture with position 1 its saves two other with postion 2

Comment: @rau.Codes My bad forgot some lines. Try now.

Comment: I removed all pictures, and added 3 new ones, all saved with ID 1 and on the third picture it got also position 2 not 3 (or the first on is not getting 3 and keeps 2)